# How to access existing table in Hive?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to access HIVE from spark application with scala.

My code:

```
val hiveLocation   = "hdfs://master:9000/user/hive/warehouse"
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SOME APP NAME").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",hiveLocation)

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("SparkHiveExample")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", hiveLocation)
  .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
println("Start of SQL Session--------------------")

spark.sql("select * from test").show()
println("End of SQL session-------------------")
```

But it ends up with error message

> Table or view not found

but when I run `show tables;` under hive console , I can see that table and can run `Select * from test`. All are in "user/hive/warehouse" location. Just for testing I tried with create table also from spark, just to find out the table location.

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
  .appName("SparkHiveExample")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", hiveLocation)
  .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
println("Start of SQL Session--------------------")
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test11(name String)")
println("End of SQL session-------------------")
```

This code also executed properly (with success note) but strange thing is that I can find this table from hive console.

Even if I use `select * from TBLS;` in mysql (in my setup I configured mysql as metastore for hive), I did not found those tables which are created from spark.

Is spark location is different than hive console?

What I have to do if I need to access existing table in hive from spark?

Answer (score 2):

from the [spark sql programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables):
(I highlighted the relevant parts)

> **Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml**,
>   core-site.xml (for security configuration), and hdfs-site.xml (for
>   HDFS configuration) file in conf/.
>
> When working with Hive, one must instantiate SparkSession with Hive
>   support, including connectivity to a persistent Hive metastore,
>   support for Hive serdes, and Hive user-defined functions. Users who do
>   not have an existing Hive deployment can still enable Hive support.
>   **When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically
>   creates metastore_db in the current directory** and creates a directory
>   configured by spark.sql.warehouse.dir, which defaults to the directory
>   spark-warehouse in the current directory that the Spark application is
>   started

you need to add a `hive-site.xml` config file to the `resource` dir.
here is the minimum needed values for spark to work with hive (set the host to the host of hive):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://host:9083</value>
        <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day , is that is the case , I can run and connect my existing hive set up after coping hive-site.xml in spark conf. But when I am running the code from IDE,intellij in my case ,  (not submit) , how can I add hive-site.xml in my code , any idea?

Comment: you have 2 options. you can add the file to the resources dir (same place as the configs files), or set that value as system property (before initializing the spark session), ie `System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://host:9083")`