# unable to access the hive table from spark-shell using sqlcontext

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

(cloudera) I have created a hive table from hive but unable to access it from the spark and created a table using sqlcontext in spark and unable to access from hive> vice versa . But i can view all tables  under hive browser interface in cloudera . how to access the table  created in hive from spark

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this will happen if you didn't configure the hive metastore url in spark

you can configure it by adding this to your `hive-site.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://host:9083</value>
        <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

see more details inmy answer to another question: [How to access existing table in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862659/how-to-access-existing-table-in-hive/46870614#46870614)